# Finding the voltage range in a series circuit

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, resistors, dc, series

Given a DC circuit with 3 resistors connected in series and the following information:

1. The resistance of R1 is 2 ohms.
2. The voltage over R2 is 20 volts.
3. The power dissipation on R3 is 25 watts.

what is the range of all possible voltages on the voltage source?

---

I formulated the voltage as a function of current:

$$V(I) = 2I + 20 + \frac{25}{I}$$

I don't know how to keep going from here

Comment: This is obvious a school assignment and we don't answer those unless you show some work yourself and tells us where you got stuck.

Comment: @MatanHaller It looks like you should take the derivative of that function and look at when it is equal to 0. - Also, keep new information that is related to your question, in your question. There is an edit button for this.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please quickly realise this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Ask a clear question, show your work and findings so far in considerable detail with any schematic. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! This appears to be a homework question. As such, you need to show us your work so far, and explain which part of the question you're having trouble with. For future reference: Homework questions on EE.SE enjoy/suffer a special treatment. We don't provide complete answers, we only provide hints or Socratic questions, and only when you have demonstrated sufficient effort of your own. Otherwise, we would be doing you a disservice, and getting swamped by homework questions at the same time. See also [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5120/7036).

Comment: Your circuit description is incomplete. You talk about three resistors in series, but then you also introduce a voltage source. How is the voltage source connected to the resistors? Are all four components in series? If so, you have three unknowns, but only enough information to write one equation. The system is underspecified, and all you can state is the obvious fact that the voltage source must be at least 20V.

Answer (score 2):

I think I came up with an answer:

Differentiating V(I) and comparing to 0 (and only considering I>0) yields a global minimum with Y value of 34.142.

Therefore: $$V_T\geq 34.142V$$